# WildFly9.0 - adding web service access

Tags: java, web-services, rest, wildfly

I am migrating my RESTful web application from GlassFish4.1 to WildFly9.0 for the first time.

Initially, I suffered deployment issues due Jersey dependencies. To overcome that problem, I simply replaced said project dependencies with RESTEasy equivalents inside of the `pom.xml` file. In doing so, my application became deployable -- and according to `(WildFly_base)/standalone/log`, and the applications themselves -- are working as expected.

Additionally, I added a `jboss-web.xml` configuration file to my WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>myprojectstart</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

The hello-world page can be reached @ http://ipaddress:8080/myprojectstart.

... however, I cannot view my web services @ http://ipaddress:8080/myprojectstart/getData, just like I could when using GlassFish-4.1.

So; what am I missing?

Note: I use `@annotations` like:

- @ApplicationPath("/*")
- @Path("/getData")

No seperate .xml business here

Comment: Try to setup the resteasy listener on your web.xml like specified here: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/#Installation_Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think RestEasy supports * in ApplicationPath. If you remove that it should work fine.

Comment: Brilliantly easy, and preserves my backwards compatibility with GlassFish!